# Youtube JSON video published date displays the date added to playlist

Tags: json, youtube, youtube-api

When getting a YouTube playlist, I want to display the published date of each video. Currently from my `var pubdate` I am getting the date the video was added to the playlist, not its published date.

```
var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLAYLISTID?v=2&alt=json&callback=?&max-results=50';
var videoURL= 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
$.getJSON(playListURL, function(data) {
    var list_data="";
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
        var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
        var pubdate  = item.published.$t;
        var fulldate = new Date(pubdate).toLocaleDateString();
        var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
        var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
        var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
        var url = videoURL + videoID;
        var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ videoID +"/mqdefault.jpg";
        list_data += '<li><a href="'+ url +'" title="'+ feedTitle +'"><img alt="'+ feedTitle+'" src="'+ thumb +'"</a><br /><a href="'+ url +'" title="'+ feedTitle +'"><strong>'+ feedTitle+'</strong></a><br />'+ fulldate +'</li>';
    });
    $(list_data).appendTo(".cont");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `console.log` into your `$each` loop to print the item data and see in the JavaScript console what field you should be using ?

`console.log(item);`

Also if you use "part=contentDetails" into the URL you fetch you will be getting more data about every items.

Comment: Thanks, it was: 
`item.media$group.yt$uploaded.$t;`